# Creating a simple constructor for a grouping of Web Audio API nodes

Tags: javascript, constructor, web-audio-api

I have a batch of Web Audio API nodes that look like the code below. I want to abstract this into a simple constructor but I'm having trouble. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The end result should look something like

```
function filterTemplate(name,freqVal){
     this.name = context.createBiquadFilter();
     this.name.type = 5;    
     this.name.gain.value = null;    
     this.name.Q.value = 1;                  
     this.name.frequency.value = this.freqVal;      // freqVal is here

}
```

When I call the function:

```
var filter = new filterTemplate("theName",200);  //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'createBiquadFilter' of undefined
```

I changed the method to look like this and the error is removed

```
this.name = function(){return context.createBiquadFilter()};
```

but then I get another error for the various property values

```
//Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
```

I'm really just confused as to the proper way to create a vanilla constructor using built in browser methods and properties.

**I want to abstract the code below into looking something like the code above**

```
filter1 = context.createBiquadFilter();
filter1.type = 5;    
filter1.gain.value = null;    
filter1.Q.value = 1;                  
filter1.frequency.value = 80;              // Changes

filter2 = context.createBiquadFilter();
filter2.type = 5;    
filter2.gain.value = 0;    
filter2.Q.value = 1;                  
filter2.frequency.value = 240;            // Changes

filter3 = context.createBiquadFilter();
filter3.type = 5;    
filter3.gain.value = 0;    
filter3.Q.value = 1;                  
filter3.frequency.value = 750;            // Changes

filter4 = context.createBiquadFilter();
filter4.type = 5;    
filter4.gain.value = 0;    
filter4.Q.value = 1;                  
filter4.frequency.value = 2200;            // Changes

filter5 = context.createBiquadFilter();
filter5.type = 5;    
filter5.gain.value = 0;    
filter5.Q.value = 1;                  
filter5.frequency.value = 6000;           // Changes
```

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: var filter = new filterTemplate(theName,200);  // Uncaught ReferenceError: theName is not defined

Comment: `theName` is not defined.

Comment: Sorry, it should be a string but there are other problems as well (edited above). I'm really just confused as to the proper way to create a vanilla constructor using built in browser methods and properties.Above post has been edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the scope of your context variable.

```
var filter = new filterTemplate("theName",200);  //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'createBiquadFilter' of undefined
```

... means that the context variable isn't available from where you're trying to reach it (which is within the filterTemplate constructor). When you do...

```
this.name = function(){return context.createBiquadFilter()};
```

... you're assigning the function to this.name instead, and it won't try to access the context until the function is run, and thus the error is removed. What happens instead is that you don't have a filter in this.name, but rather a function, and a function doesn't have a gain property and therefore you get an error when you try to set this.name.gain.value.

What you should look for is where you define the context, and make sure it's possible to access that variable from within filterTemplate.

Comment: Ok, so adding var context = new webkitAudioContext(); within the function seems to eradicate all errors. But is it "bloat" to do that? I would like to have one AudioContext(); accessible to the entire program. I figure that is better etiquette. Thanks btw

Comment: Yes, definitely one context for the entire program. The easiest way to make it accessible is to define it on the same level as as filterTemplate. Without seeing the entire code it's hard to give a better advice than that. :)

Comment: I think my problem is I defined the AudioContext(); below the function instead of above it...lol. I always over analyze everything and it's very entertaining in retrospect. I could delete this post but I think I will leave it for entertainment purposes unless prompted to do otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The builder pattern is very nice for this situation. Especially when you can set a lot of properties.

http://jsfiddle.net/yw8Fm/

You can create a simple `FilterTemplate` class like this.

```
function FilterTemplate(builder) {
    this.context = builder._context;
    this.context.type = builder._type;    
    this.context.gain.value = builder._gainValue;    
    this.context.Q.value = builder._qValue;                  
    this.context.frequency.value = builder._frequencyValue;
}
```

It takes a builder object as constructor argument. Here is the `Builder`.

```
FilterTemplate.Builder = function () {
    this._context = context.createBiquadFilter();
    this._type = 5;    
    this._gainValue = null;    
    this._qValue = 1;                  
    this._frequencyValue = 80;

    this.context = function (val) { 
        this._context = val; return this; 
    };

    this.type = function (val) { 
        this._type = val; return this; 
    };

    this.gainValue = function (val) { 
        this._gainValue = val; return this; 
    };

    this.qValue = function (val) { 
        this._qValue = val; return this; 
    };

    this.frequencyValue = function (val) { 
        this._frequencyValue = val; return this; 
    };
};
```

You can further extend this example as you like.
Now you can create `FilterTemplates` with ease.

```
var filter1 = new FilterTemplate(
    (new FilterTemplate.Builder()).frequencyValue(80)
);

var filter2 = new FilterTemplate(
    (new FilterTemplate.Builder()).frequencyValue(80).qValue(2)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This looks neat. I forked it.